# React-native-ignite didn't install dependencies

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

So I do everything correctly, but after I run

```
ignite new MyApplication
```

this appears:

```
⠋ Copying Ignite goodies
➟ Package manager:  [ ]︎ npm  |  [✔︎]︎ yarn
 Installing Ignite dependencies (~ 1 minute-ish)
✔︎ Linking external libs
✔︎ Updating android manifest file
⠋ Updating android manifest file/bin/sh: 1: plutil: not found
✔︎ Updating PList file
✔︎ Cleaning up after messy guests

Time to get cooking!  

To run in iOS:
  cd MyApplication
  react-native run-ios

To run in Android:
  cd MyApplication
  react-native run-android
```

So it shows an 'x' on "Installing dependencies"
And when i run application with "react-native run-android"
it says build succesfull, but in the emulator error shows up:

```
Requiring unknown module "reduxsauce".If
you are sure the module is there, try
restarting the packager or running "npm
install".
```

And i tried it but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

make in project folder:

```
yarn
```

or

```
npm install
```